# jquery autocomplete on 'paste' eveny

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my code

```
$("#stockNo2").bind("paste", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#stockNo2").autocomplete("search", $("#stockNo2").val());
        }, 0);
    });
```

I wanted to trigger autocomplete on paste event. But when I try it I get the error

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'search'

Comment: Error message very clearly explains the problem.

Comment: If the target has not been initialized as Autocomplete, you cannot call `search` upon it.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you need to initialize the autocomplete first.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
$("#stockNo2").autocomplete({
  source: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
});
$("#stockNo2").bind("paste", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#stockNo2").autocomplete("search", $("#stockNo2").val());
  }, 0);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abaevrtg/

Also note that `.bind` has been deprecated for a while, you should use `.on` instead.

Comment: Does it count as initializing if the autocomplete in the first block of your code is wrapped by a 'on keydown' event handler?

Comment: I think that would do it, since `keydown` will occur before `paste`, even if only by a few ms.